# Tabulate installed but interpreter can't resolve the import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've written a script to use the tabulate library, but for some reason the script isn't able to resolve the import.
when I run `pip install tabulate` into my terminal I get this:

`Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.8.9)`

so tabulate should already be installed, but my script gives this error:

`import "tabulate" could not be resolved from source" Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)`

I've installed many other libraries and they're working fine, but for some reason I can't get this one to work.

For reference here's the call in my script:

`from tabulate import tabulate`

I've also run the pip install tabulate from the windows command prompt, from vscode (the text editor I'm writing in), and from the python application where the command doesn't seem to work at all.
This is on python 3.9.
I've also tried other variations of the pip install command, they all return the same "Requirement already satisfied" message.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Can you try `python3 -m pip install tabulate`?

Comment: python 3.9 @reddynishanth

Comment: I tried that and it didn't change anything, same "requirement satisfied" response

Comment: Did you also try `pip3 install tabulate`? If this also doesn't work, can you uninstall it and re-install it?

Comment: well, I just realized that the code still runs oddly, even though I get the error.

Comment: Are you using vscode? Where are you seeing that import missing thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your interpreter in vscode!

Go to:

> View > Command Palette.

Then type this:

> Python: Select Interpreter

Then choose the one that installed in that directory(the "python39" dir in this your case!).

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: This resolved it! It was weird because my other library imports were working but only the tabulate wasn't. I'm not really sure why that was. but doing this got tabulate and the rest still working.